# access denied for user "@'localhost for database 'db_name'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I installed MySQL with package installer on Mac OS x, then I ran query browser and connected to database with `username = ""` and `password = ""`. Now, I want to create a new schema,
when a type `create schema rest`, it shows an error like `access denied for user "@'localhost' to database 'rest'`

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in with username "root" and password "".